# How to Exclude Log Using Fail2Ban logpath with Wildcard Settings

Tags: linux, iptables, monitoring, fail2ban, web-crawler

I'm using wildcard in the logpath value as shown below:

```
[http-get-dos]
enabled = true
filter = http-get-dos
logpath = /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/*/access.log
maxretry = 250
findtime = 300
#ban for 10 hours
bantime = 36000
action = iptables-multiport[name=HTTP, port="http,https", protocol=tcp]
```

This works great but I want to exclude specific log because I need to create a separate filter for this.

So, for example, if I want to exclude /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/mysite.com/access.log, how do I do this?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do but  `logpath = /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/!(mysite.com)/access.log`  might be an option.

Comment: As I've said I will create a separate filter. like another [http-get-dos2]. I tested your suggestion but it still it add to logpath as fail2ban.log stated as follows `Added logfile = /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/mysite.com/access.log`.

Comment: If you can use globs `*` you will be able to use `!` negate too. Did you restart fail2ban / iptables.

Comment: Yes, I already restarted fail2ban.